# Accessing viewbinding object in a non view class?

Tags: android, data-binding, android-viewbinding

In my fragment I am using a bottom sheet to show some UI components

This is my fragment xml

```
 <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        >
        <!--            other views -->
        <include
            android:id="@+id/feedbackIncluded"
            layout="@layout/chat_feedback" />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I currently handle view actions or data of bottomsheet from my fragment.

I am planning to seperate the code for bottomsheet handling to another class

This is my bottom sheet xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
app:behavior_hideable="false"
app:behavior_peekHeight="16dp"
app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

<data>


</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/parentSheetLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

 <!--        some views -->
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

This is the class which I have created where I want to do the handling

```
class ChatFeedbackBottomSheet(context: Context) {
var binding: ChatFeedbackBinding? = null

init {
     binding = ChatFeedbackBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), null, false)
    println(binding?.option1.text)
}

fun openSheet() {
    println("------>" + binding?.option1?.text)
}

}
```

I can't seem to figure how do I get the correct viewbinding object in this class?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have another class for refactoring of code, you can just take out the function and keep it inside another file, You can pass view binding variables in the function parameters and execute your code there.